# Downloaded PEM cert but still getting "unable to get local issuer certificate"

Tags: php, ssl, curl

I'm trying to create a proxy server where I will be requesting a JSON object from an API using curl. I've been able to successfully make this work except for the certification.

```
<?php
error_reporting(E_ALL);

$url = "https://query.yahooapis.com/v1/public/yql?q=select%20*%20from%20csv%20where%20url%3D'http%3A%2F%2Ffinance.yahoo.com%2Fd%2Fquotes.csv%3Fs%3DMSFT%2BFFIV%26f%3Dnab'&format=json&diagnostics=true&callback=";

$ch = curl_init($url);

curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, 2);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CAINFO, getcwd() . "\VeriSignClass3PublicPrimaryCertificationAuthority-G5.crt");
// Perform the request, and save content to $result
$result = curl_exec($ch);
if(curl_errno($ch)){
echo 'Curl error: ' . curl_error($ch);
} else {
    echo $result;
}
exit();
?>
```

I've already downloaded the yahooapis certification PEM file (with and without chain) and placed it in the same folder level as the proxy.php file, but I'm still getting the error "unable to get local issuer certificate".

Any ideas on what might be missing?

Also, please do not suggest to set CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER to false, as I know this bypasses verification. I need the server to verify before it connects.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

> curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CAINFO, getcwd() . "\VeriSignClass3PublicPrimaryCertificationAuthority-G5.crt");

I don't think this is the right one. You need the G3 and not the G5 certificate with the fingerprint 74:2C:31:92:E6:07:E4:24:EB:45:49:54:2B:E1:BB:C5:3E:61:74:E2. The G5 certificate will not work with OpenSSL stack with the setup used by query.yahooapis.com because of problems of OpenSSL with alternative trust path. For more details look at http://kriscience.blogspot.de/2013/03/supporting-trusted-but-untrusted.html.

Comment: I downloaded the G3 certificate and the fingerprint is indeed different. Do you happen to have a link to another public API that I could test that would have this fingerprint/cert? Doesn't matter what the output is as long as it's JSON.

Comment: No, I don't know of any other API.